# ErrorException Arrays to String conversion laravel 4 and Moloquent

Tags: mongodb, laravel-4

Good day,

I'm currently using Moloquent by jenseggers and laravel 4...

Everything works fine and even tried to get the lastname using this code to see if it's working

```
{{ $userGroup->lastname }}
```

and it's working fine, **BUT** when I tried to access **groups** by doing this

```
{{ $userGroup->groups }}
```

it throws an

```
ErrorException Array to string conversion (View: /var/www/laravel-learnapolis/app/views/dashboard/main.blade.php)`
```

tried doing var_dump and it gives me this output (working fine)

```
{{ var_dump($userGroup->groups) }}
```

**Result**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["groupID"]=>
    string(12) "140368641573"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "aw"
    ["description"]=>
    string(2) "wa"
    ["dateCreated"]=>
    object(MongoDate)#187 (2) {
      ["sec"]=>
      int(1403686415)
      ["usec"]=>
      int(521000)
    }
  }
```

**------- For Reference ----------**

**Mongo**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("53a800a2abd28e07068b4567"),
"email" : "my@email.com",
"firstname" : "firstname",
"lastname" : "lastname",
"password" : "$2y$10$hUGZhkHWBKKxvk4n1LU16OYWeALlYxeU6C15UvzH1ic.gJ7O4uCsu",
"hash" : "",
"active" : 1,
"updated_at" : ISODate("2014-06-24T10:43:21.958Z"),
"remember_token" : "NSint7eLHFuxbDKRkpK11qyIUDDtS06LaBJt0MgwsjElrUllpORBbN8YVoSL",
"groups" : [
    {
        "groupID" : "140368641573",
        "name" : "aw",
        "description" : "wa",
        "dateCreated" : ISODate("2014-06-25T08:53:35.521Z")
    }
]
```

}

**Controller**

```
public function dashboard() {
    $userID = Auth::user()->_id;

    $user = User::where('_id','=',$userID);

    if ( $user->count() ) {
        $user = $user->first();
        return View::make('dashboard.main')
                        ->with('userGroup', $user);
    }

}
```

**View (blade)**

**works fine**

```
{{ $userGroup }}
```

**won't work**

```
{{ $userGroup->groups }}
```

Just having some hard time with this though, hope someone could help me. I'm a newbie with laravel but I do have an experience with MongoDB.. Tried searching to uncle google, but haven't got any solution(s) that solves the problem..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing some codes like instead of using

```
User::where
```

change it with this

```
User::find
```

I don't know, what's the difference between the two though but thank goodness it works now.. but feel free to give an explanation regarding this..

**Controller**

```
public function dashboard() {
    $user = User::find( Auth::user()->_id );

    if ( $user->count() ) {
        return View::make('dashboard.main')
                    ->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@if ( is_array($user->groups) )
    @foreach ( $user->groups as $grp )
        {{ $grp['name'] }}
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Groups is an array (I'm guessing its a "many" relationship)

So you need to do this

```
@foreach ($userGroup->groups as $group)
    {{{ $group->name }}}
@endforeach
```

And that way it will list the name for each group.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response.. Actually, I've done that already but no luck, since firstly, $userGroup->groups displays an ErrorException that I mentioned above, so I can't actually access it's inner data... but when I do var_dump, it displays the actual data...

Comment: I've checked if it's a valid JSON format, but it's ok, so I'm just wondering how can't I access, the inner data under group... hmmm.. hope someone could help.. -_-